# Fade effect on the ui-panel-dismiss when open/closing panels (like Android)

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, fade

I work on a specific Android application (compagnon app for visitors in an event), using *PhoneGapp* framewok. So my app is only a web page, with Jquery and Jquery Mobile.

I want to simulate the same panel effect viewable in Android when a side panel is openned (Gmail is a good demonstration of the effect) :

- App full screen
- During 350ms, the panel begin sliding AND the opacity of the app decrease
- Slide end, and opacity is now at 0.6 (with black bakcground, of course)

So, all is perfect in my app (opacity, background, etc...), except the fading animation when a panel is open.

**My question is** : how i can make a 350ms fad-in/out on the **ui-panel-dismiss** div when a panel is openned/closed ? (and if possible, in CSS only).

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try jQuery method "animate" ? http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Or css transition : http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Oh I didn't thought of that, thank you for the information. I'll do it next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create own transformation [Link1](http://www.packtpub.com/library/jquery-mobile-cookbook/ch02lvl1sec18)

create own js function if you get confused then open  jquery.mobile.js file and see what they do for page transformation effect

```
$.mobile.transitionHandlers["slidefade"] = mycustomTransition;


function mycustomTransition( name, reverse, $to, $from ) {
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
// Define your custom animation here
$to.width("0");
$to.height("0");
$to.show();
$from.animate(
    { width: "0", height: "0", opacity: "0" },
    { duration: 750 },
    { easing: 'easein' }
);
$to.animate(
    { width: "100%", height: "100%", opacity: "1" },
    { duration: 750 },
    { easing: 'easein' }
);
// Standard template from jQuery Mobile JS file
reverseClass = reverse ? " reverse" : "";
viewportClass 
  = "ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-" + name;
$to.add( $from ).removeClass( "out in reverse " + name );
if ( $from && $from[ 0 ] !== $to[ 0 ] ) {
   $from.removeClass( $.mobile.activePageClass );
}
$to.parent().removeClass( viewportClass );
deferred.resolve( name, reverse, $to, $from );
$to.parent().addClass( viewportClass );
if ( $from ) {
  $from.addClass( name + " out" + reverseClass );
}
$to.addClass( $.mobile.activePageClass + " " + name 
  + " in" + reverseClass );
return deferred.promise();
}
```

you can try it on Fiddle first here [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/Y4Rvx/)